# What order is used by First() function?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Why do the following two queries return identical results?

```
SELECT FIRST(score) FROM (SELECT score FROM scores ORDER BY score ASC)
SELECT FIRST(score) FROM (SELECT score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC)
```

It's confusing, considering that I manually specify the order of subqueries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the results in the subquery is irrelevant, unless you use TOP within the subquery, which you don't here.  Most SQL variants won't allow this syntax -- using an ORDER BY in a subquery throws an error in SQL Server, for example.

Your top-level query has no ORDER BY, thus the concepts of FIRST or TOP 1 are undefined in the context of *that* query.

In the [reference docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177902%28v=office.12%29.aspx), Microsoft states (emphasis mine):

> Because records are usually returned in no particular order (unless
>   the query includes an ORDER BY clause), the records returned by these
>   functions will be **arbitrary**.

Comment: I don't have Access here to test on, you may be right about the FIRST() function.  The "meat" of my response is the first paragraph -- that ORDER BY in the subquery is irrelevant, and an error in most dialects.  I will edit my response.

Comment: But including an Order By clause requires that all fields in the Order By are also in aggregate expressions.  But if the Order By includes multiple fields, putting those fields in aggregate functions or the Group By clause essentially destroys the aggregate behavior of First() since it produced multiple rows for unique combination of all the fields.  So the First() function is only useful when sorting on the _same, single_ field... but then it is equivalent to the Min() and Max() functions. Thus, the answer is sufficient for the original question, but not universally applicable.

Answer (score 3):

**To answer the question directly:**

Access ignores the `ORDER BY` clause in most subqueries.  I beleive (but can't prove) this is due to bugs/limitations in the query optimiser, although it's not documented anywhere (that I could find).  I've tested lots of SQL using Access 2007 and Access 2016 to come to this conclusion.

**To make the examples work as expected:**

Add `TOP 100 PERCENT` to the subqueries:

```
SELECT FIRST(score) FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT score FROM scores ORDER BY score ASC)
SELECT FIRST(score) FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC)
```

**When to use `First`/`Last` instead of `Max`/`Min`:**

A good example of when you'd want to use this approach instead of the simpler `Min` and `Max` aggregate functions is when there's another field that you want from the same record, e.g if the underlying `scores` table also held the `name`s of players and the `round`s of the game, you can get the `name` and `score` of the best and worst player in each `round` like this:

```
SELECT
  round, FIRST(name) AS best, FIRST(score) AS highscore, LAST(name) AS worst, LAST(score) AS lowscore
FROM
  (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC)
GROUP BY
  round
```

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier to do `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM scores ORDER BY score ASC`? I have never found a real application of First(), except perhaps in "just give me any value, I don't need aggregation" situations e.g. in some crosstab queries.

Comment: @Andre if you mean in the subquery then, yes, but I tend to go for `TOP 100 PERCENT` because that also works in the general case where there's a `GROUP BY` clause in the outer query, i.e. I want the `First` value in each group not just the First value from the whole query.  The only time I've used `First` is where I'd normally use analytic/window functions (like my last example) but Access doesn't support them.  Also note that `TOP 1` in Access actually returns multiple rows, e.g. if there are multiple players with the same score.

Comment: Actually I meant as replacement for the whole query. But -- *Also note that TOP 1 in Access actually returns multiple rows for identical values* -- I was not aware of this :-o. I guess I only ever used it with unique / key columns.

Answer (score -2):

Your statements are a **perfect functional equivalents** to
`SELECT Min(Score) FROM Scores` and
`SELECT Max(Score) FROM Scores`.
If you really want to retrieve the first and last score, you will need an AutoNumber or a DateTime field to indicate the input order. You could then query:

```
SELECT First(Score), Last(Score) FROM Scores ORDER BY MySortKey
```

If you persist with your question, the correct syntax would be
`SELECT FIRST(score) FROM (SELECT score FROM scores) ORDER BY score ASC`,
or, simplified,
`SELECT FIRST(score) FROM scores ORDER BY score ASC`

Comment: @HansUp: that code is to illustrate the paragraph preceding it. I edited my reply, changing the name GameID by MySortKey. Obviously, it needs a field with that name in the table or replace the name in the SQL statement...

Comment: Why did the only valid response so far to this question receive a -1 ?

Comment: +1: good point. I am not spiteful. But except for the Null case, I maintain that my answer is good, and the question is somehow meaningless.